# Can one buy a licence to customize stack exchange

Tags: discussion

I am looking for a product.  Basically exactly stack exchange but for a custom internal application.

We want to implement a Q&A site with reputation into our existing customer base.

I'm open to paying or open source solution.

Self hosted or cloud